# How to route one page to another using react native?

Tags: react-native

I am building a very basic app for testing react native routing. Here my code...

index.android.js

```
    constructor() {
    super();
}

renderScene(route, navigator) {
    if(route.name === 'loginPage') {
        return <Login navigator={navigator}/>
    } else if (route.name === 'homePage') {
        alert('**********');
        return <Home navigator={navigator}/>
    }

}
```

render() {

```
return (

  <Navigator

    initialRoute={{name: 'loginPage' }}

    renderScene= {(name) => this.renderScene(name)}

  />
);
```

}

Login Page

constructor() {

```
    super();

   this.navigate = this.navigate.bind(this)

}
```

navigate(name) {

```
this.props.navigate.push( {

   name 

})
```

}

render() {

```
    return (

         <Button
                onPress={() => this.apiCalling('homePage')}
                title="API Call"

                accessibilityLabel="See an informative alert"
            />
       );
 }
```

}

but here I am getting error. The error is " undefined is not object ( evaluating 'this.props.navigator.push )

How may I resolve it...?

Comment: for simplicity use https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux

Answer (score 0):

You are doing "this.props.navigate" while the prop being passed is called "navigator"